# Create folder in Android

Tags: java, android, file

```
 import java.io.File;  
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TollCulator");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Does Not Exist, Create It", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed - Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The above should create a folder in my SD card if it does not exist, if it does then don't do anything. Although the toast works based on the condition but it doesn't create a directory when it does not exist. Any idea how to resolve it?

My `Manifest` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="6"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.testing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Update**: I updated my manifest as well as updated my code but it's still not creating the folder in my SD card. Keep in mind, I am using Eclipse and running the app directly to my phone (GNex VZW) instead of using an AVD.

Comment: hv u added permisions

Comment: Perhaps you need to add filesystem write permissions to your app's manifest.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Add this permission in `Manifest`,
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                             File.separator + "TollCulator");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success
} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
}
```

> when u run the application go too DDMS->File Explorer->mnt
>   folder->sdcard folder->toll-creation folder

Comment: I updated my question as to how I have the application installed.

Comment: are u able to create now?

Comment: I get the message Directory Created but no folder in my sdcard.

Comment: r u debuging ur app on device or emulator?

Comment: debuggin directly to device.

Comment: just debug once in emulator if still not sloved mail the code

Comment: email sent to your address.

Comment: Did not know about `File.separator`. Thanks

Comment: The code in this answer, especially in its original form, looks *very* similar to [this answer by Gopinath from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853814). Although, admittedly, so does the OP's code, so I suppose the similarity might be just coincidental. It's probably still at least worth noting.

Comment: @KOTIOS where to put this code???

Comment: API 30 Not working. thanks

Answer (score 20):

If you are trying to make more than just one folder on the root of the sdcard, 
ex. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Example/Ex App/"`

then instead of `folder.mkdir()` you would use `folder.mkdirs()`

I've made this mistake in the past & I took forever to figure it out.

Comment: Just trying to create one folder and later on check each time the app runs to see if it exists and not create another one.

Comment: in android 13 this code is not worked. 
Note:- I already give
READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_IMAGES android 13 specific permission