# How to create folder in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have stuck up with creation of folder in my mobile which is (Micromax Canvas 2).I cant able to create folder.please tel me where i made mistake.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Example");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Any error? Have you tested what returns `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

Comment: its showing path like/mnt/sdcard/appname but in success it shows false ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android

Comment: As per documentation: `Returns false on failure or if the directory already existed.`

Comment: but folder is not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.. I have declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` after the application tag.So it didnt works. I declared permission before application tag.Now folder had been created.

Answer (score 3):

```
File f1 = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"");
fol = new File(f1, "Images");
if(!fol.exists())
{
    fol.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Example");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Use *getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()* instead of just *getExternalStorageDirectory()*.

Comment: still cant able to create folder gautham

Comment: I hope you have checked in your sdcard manually if the folder is created

Comment: ya i checked ..but folder is not created which i specified

Answer (score 1):

I implement like this. Instead of "plus(+)" write with a "comma(,)"

```
 File imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                 "folder name");
 imageFileFolder.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first add permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then add FolderInfo.Class

```
package com.xxx.cg;

    import java.io.File;

    import android.os.Environment;

    public class FolderInfo {
        public static final String SDCARD;
        static {
            SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        }
        public static final String CG_FOLDER = SDCARD + "/CG";

        public static String ASSET_FOLDER = CG_FOLDER + "/assets";

        public static boolean createFolderForCG() {
            boolean exist = false;
            File dir = new File(CG_FOLDER);
            if (dir.exists()) {
                exist = true;
            } else {
                if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            return exist;
        }

        public static boolean createAssetsFolderForCG() {
            boolean exist = false;
            File dir = new File(ASSET_FOLDER);
            if (dir.exists()) {
                exist = true;
            } else {
                if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            return exist;
        }

        public static boolean createFolder(String folder) {
            boolean exist = false;
            File dir = new File(ASSET_FOLDER + "/" + folder);
            if (dir.exists()) {
                exist = true;
            } else {
                if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            return exist;
        }

    }
```

then call from your activity. such as MainActivity.Class.

```
        FolderInfo.createFolderForCG();
    FolderInfo.createAssetsFolderForCG();
            FolderInfo.createFolder(subFolderName);
```

then run. You can show CG/assets your SD Card.
and also sub folders show CG/assets/.................

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
String downloadDirectory = "/folderName";
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
        File newDownloadDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory
                + downloadDirectory);
        newDownloadDirectory.mkdir();
```

Comment: still cant able to create a folder

Comment: no error folder is not created in sdcard.. its showing path..In make directory it showing boolean false