# Can't see my folder or files after creating in other applications

Tags: android, file, save, directory

I have a small app that when I run it make a folder in my SD then save some Videos inside the folder

The thing is the app does the work and make the folder and save the files and I still can see it in SD using file manager or from my PC when I connect it via USB

But for e.g **when I start Whatsup or my Gallery I can't see the folder or the videos !**

I still can see the folder and videos that stored in the SD using File Manager

so what's wrong ? why I can't see the folder and videos in the Gallery or other programs when I want to attach the video ..

I used the same code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17795025/3898539) for my App to create the folder and check  :

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TollCulator");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success
} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gallery works off of `MediaStore`, and WhatsApp may as well. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and [its `scanFile()` static method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) to arrange to have your file(s) be indexed and available through the `MediaStore`, and see if that helps.

Comment: works thanks ! Question : should I use the MediaScannerConnection at the beginning of the activity when it run or keep it after my function and things are loaded? what's the right way

Comment: @boudi: You need to wait until the file is written with the desired contents.

Answer (score 2):

```
You need to Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is immediately available to the user.
```

For example

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
```