# permission android to create a folder in Android memory

Tags: java, android, directory, permissions

My problem is that for an Android project I have to create a folder in the external memory of the phone and this can be done for Android 11[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZlci.jpg) and lower phones.
What permissions and codes should I add to my project?

Answer (score 0):

if you have to support Android 11 then you have to support Scoped Storage for accessing whole storage, not only app-restricted folder (basing on screen of external root folder). check out [THIS](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) doc for more

question is which perms are needed, so for full access to whole content you need

```
// works till Android 9/10
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

// for Android 10/11
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I strongly suggest: don't use second permission, store your data in app-restricted folder (as stays in linked doc, `getExternalFilesDirs()` method), then just `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will be sufficient

and how to create folder? [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android) you have some examples, just don't use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, instead use `getExternalFilesDirs()` for accessing app-restricted folder (or use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but then you need second permission declared for Android 11)

Answer (score 0):

For an Android 11 device:

Use Storage Access Framework and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user create and choose that Pixir directory.

Not a single permission needed.

After that you can create as much files and subdirs in it as you want using saf methods.

If a directory Documents/Pixir could do too than you could use your old classic files code and usual permissions to create files and folders in it.