# can't create folder on externalstorage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm trying to create a folder on external storage with no success.Although i've managed to create a folder in my app's directory, i can't do the same for external storage and i also get `false` when i call `canWrite()`.I have declared the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION` on manifest.

Here is my code for my app's directory

```
 File file1=new File(context.getFilesDir(), "//test1");
 file1.mkdir();
 System.out.println(file1.canWrite());
```

and for ExternalStorage respectively

```
File file2=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "//test2");
file2.mkdir();
System.out.println(file2.canWrite());
```

In the first case the folder gets created and i get true on println.On the second one folder does not get created and i get false on println.

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the duplicate slashes. Beyond that, [you appear to be having problems getting the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create folder on external storage on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366217/cant-create-folder-on-external-storage-on-android)

Comment: @CommonsWare That was very helpful.The problem was that i was targeting version 23.I would never have found it!

Answer (score 0):

Add Below Permission i your manifest.xml
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

```
          String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/YourPath";
          String fileName="Name for your File";           

          File file = new File(PATH);
          file.mkdirs();

          File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

          InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int len1 = 0;
          while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
          {

              fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
          }
          fos.close();
          is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a directory,if you use comma,it means "//test2" will become a file name

```
String string = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test2";
File file = new File(string, "file_name");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileOutputStream.write(your_data);
fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: I get your point but the problem was i could't write anything when i called getExternalStorageDirectory, file or directory

Comment: FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                fileOutputStream.write(your data);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();