# How to create Android directory automatically if it doesn't already exist

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am creating a gallery app using a tutorial but get the following error:

**abc directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class**

Please visit the following link to see the entire tutorial's code as I am using the same code:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

I found this code in `Utils` Class:

else {
                // image directory is empty
                Toast.makeText(
                        _context,
                        AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                                + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

```
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.show();
    }

    return filePaths;
```

How can I create the missing directory programmatically instead of display this error dialog?

Comment: Already Resolved - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card

Comment: i updated my question please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a directory in /sdcard fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails)

Answer (score 12):

Here's how you create directories if they don't exist. Considering that `directory` is indeed a directory.

```
// If the parent dir doesn't exist, create it
if (!directory.exists()) {
    if (parentDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully created the parent dir:" + parentDir.getName());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create the parent dir:" + parentDir.getName());
    }
}
```

`mkdirs()` will also create missing parent directories (i.e. all directories that lead to `directory`).

Comment: @user3739970 What's wrong with my answer? Just add this code before `if (directory.isDirectory())`. The directory will be created if it doesn't exist and you shouldn't be getting the `Toast` anymore so you can remove the `else` portion.