# Error when i choose large image

Tags: java, android, database

I am converting my imageview to byte it will work fine when i select min size images i.e. 20kb-300kb approx but when i select image captured by mobile camera it shows the error.

```
private byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

My sql query is

```
sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name DROPDOWN, price VARCHAR, image BLOB)");
```

At the decode image i use

```
byte[] foodImage = food.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And my cursor for getting data is

```
Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        // int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Notice(id,name, price, image));
    }
```

And i got the error i.e.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard, PID: 4122
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard/com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.NoticeActivityAll}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
                  at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
                  at com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.NoticeActivityAll.onCreate(NoticeActivityAll.java:58)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

Plz help mee, i am trying to solve this issue from to many days but i can't done it.

Comment: Maybe this can help? Looks like there is  Cursor size limit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406429/cursor-size-limit-in-android-sqlitedatabase https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/pull/4033

Comment: I would suggest storing the files in a storage folder on the device and store the file paths in the SQLite database then use the paths to read the images from the device's file storage

Comment: sir, can you give me sample code for that, because i started learning android a month ago so i don't know how to do that. @Chester Cobus  and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing file:

```
private String saveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File file = null;

  try {
    file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Food"), fileName);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Reading file:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(food.getImageUrl(), options);
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Don't forget to add these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

SQLite query updated:

```
sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name DROPDOWN, price VARCHAR, imageUrl VARCHAR)");
```

Update your Notice object to have imageUrl then cursor code looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
list.clear();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    // int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
    String name = cursor.getString(1);
    String price = cursor.getString(2);
    String imageUrl = cursor.getString(3);

    list.add(new Notice(id,name, price, imageUrl));
}
```

Comment: what changes i will do in that

    sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                            selectbranch.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(),
                            edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                            imageViewToByte(imageView) );

Comment: sqLiteHelper.insertData( selectbranch.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(), edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(), saveFile(imageView, "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())));

Comment: imageView shows an error i.e.
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.widget.ImageView', required: 'android.graphics.Bitmap' 
saveFile (android.graphics.Bitmap,   String) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (android.widget.ImageView,  String)

Comment: sqLiteHelper.insertData( selectbranch.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(), edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(), saveFile(((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())));

Comment: image.getDrawable()

first image gives error that multiple choice i import R.id.Image then getDrawable method gives error and said add qualifier imageView to method when i pressed alt+enter

Comment: sqLiteHelper.insertData( selectbranch.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(), edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(), saveFile(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), "IMG_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())));

Comment: it's imageView not image sorry

Comment: Wrong 3rd argument type. found: 'java.lang.String'. required 'byte[]'

Comment: please refactor your code by moving them into variables so you can see your argument issues.

Comment: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Food/IMG_20170326_103104: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: sir, i refactor code then pressed alt+enter then error gone and my application run but at the run time file not found exception is occurred and it is not shown in which activity this exception is present,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202977/how-to-create-android-directory-automatically-if-it-doesnt-already-exist

Comment: I create directory manually in my mobile and afterword it works finally.
Thank you so much sir...

Comment: Now directory is also automatically created by referring above question thanks again.