# Video is not saving?

Tags: android

So, I'm trying to save a mp4 file from a temp file to the picture directory. The tablet works fine. But it's not working on a samsung nexus. It's not even creating the directory.

```
 private void moveFileToGallery() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME, ": Failed to create directory");

                return;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());

        String videoFileName = "VID_"+timeStamp+".mp4";
        File source= new File("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        File destination= new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/"+videoFileName);

        source.renameTo(destination);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video Saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What error you are getting? and can you access the file source video?

Comment: Yes I can access the source file. The codes went thru, but when I check the file in the directory, it's not there.

Answer (score 3):

Print the log of your destination path.
I think it is having two slashes.(//).Because you are writing File.seperator+"/".
Print the log and check the path.

Comment: my bad guys actually, i removed "/" in my code already. But it's still not saving the video.

Comment: Directory is created?? and see if your method source.renameTo(destination); returns true or false..Use debugging..

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
File destination= new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+"/"+videoFileName);
```

to this

```
File destination= new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + videoFileName);
```

you are using an extra `"/"` which is not required when you are using `File.separator`. Check if this solve your problem

Comment: my bad guys actually, i removed "/" in my code already.  But it's still not saving the video to my nexus.

Comment: Do you get any error or exception when testing on nexus?

Comment: Is directory has been created on your phone ??

Comment: Nope, the directory is not created.

Comment: @tipsywacky Put my code instead of your's. It will definitely works! Just try it! I have checked from my side

Comment: Please visit this question [Creating a directory in /sdcard fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails)

Comment: And please check androidmenifest if you have given this permission to your app `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
private void moveFileToGallery() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myvideo");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("myvideo", ": Failed to create directory");

                return;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        String videoFileName = "VID_"+timeStamp+".mp4";
        File source= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myvideo.mp4");
        File destination= new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + videoFileName);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(source));
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            copyStream(inputStream, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video Saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Add this function too:

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is my code also works on another android tablet. It just doesn't work on a samsung nexus.

Comment: I think the problem is the directory is not even created.

Comment: @tipsywacky Mine is working on both, you should skip your code and go for my code. Hope it works for you too!