# Cannot create directory in external storage although permissions are apparently set correctly

Tags: java, android, galaxy

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest file, however I fail when trying to create a directory

```
    Log.d(LOG_STRING, android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState() );
    java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "test");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        Log.d(LOG_STRING, "Created directory");
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_STRING, "FAILED WHILE CREATING DIRECTORY");
    }
```

The status of external storage is "mounted", but the `test` directory cannot be created and the output is `"FAILED WHILE CREATING DIRECTORY"`.

Browsing in the phone to the "App Info", the permission "modify or delete the contents of your USB storage" is marked to be activated for my application.

What could be the cause of this? Some special setting of the phone? It's a Samsung GT-I9506 with Android 4.3 (API18). To be noted is that the `getExternalStorageDirectory` is not on the SD card, but on the internal storage (`/storage/emulated/0/`).

---

**Update:**

Speaking with colleagues, it seems that this device has undergone several tweaking after having been rooted (to allow a specific application to directly write on the SD card). It's probably not worth to investigate further, I will simply switch to another device. I'll keep the device for a while and if anybody will show up with an answer I will quickly test if it solves the problem.

---

**Update 2: (Bounty end)**

The problem remains unsolved, but as stated before, it is most likely something very specific to this one device. It's not possible to write on any path, being it external or internal storage, not even in the path returned by `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Comment: If you are not on kitkat this should not be a problem. Can you try to debug the sdcard state as explained here and post the results? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: @bonnyz I know it's not the complete test, but as a first quick feedback, just before trying to create the directory the following returns true: `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState() )` (according to the code you linked, that should give write access).

Comment: yes you're right. Did you managed to test on other devices?

Comment: Something wrong in /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml maybe.

Comment: @bonnyz With a Galaxy Note 4 (API21) it works.

Comment: Maybe you are running out of space on the Samsung GT-I9506? Just guessing, try to check the available space and then reboot the phone.

Comment: @bonnyz Hmm... There's plenty of space and I rebooted several times. I have to investigate more about the history of this device with my colleagues.

Comment: Yea I was just guessing ;) Keep us updated, I'm courious!

Comment: can you make a directory by handling in /storage/emulated/0/?  and can you read files from getExternalStorageDirectory()?

Comment: @Antonio Have you tried using mkdirs api? The File.mkdirs() method will create all needed directories; mkdir() will only create the last directory in the pathname.I think it may work and during debugging if USB option is selected as MTP or File Transfer then SDCard won't be available

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar My code creates only one folder (no subfolder) in the directory returned by `getExternalStorageState()`

Comment: @Antonio   mkdirs will make sure all the folders are available/created. Have you checked whether storage is mounted by code like this    `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);`

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar If you see the code and explanation in the question, I am calling getExternalStorageState and the device results to be mounted. As explained above in the comments, `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState‌​() )` also returns true.

Comment: Please try this one once : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7439425/4596556

Comment: @Tron Sorry, I could not verify that because I cannot install a File Manager

Comment: @Tron I am now able to access `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml`, what should I look for?

Comment: Look for android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (internal storage should be **<group gid=”sdcard_rw” />**, external SD card <group gid=”media_rw” />). As it is on: http://www.sammobile.com/2013/08/11/android-4-3-on-galaxy-s4-google-edition-breaks-sd-card-writing-for-apps-heres-a-fix/

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails

Comment: @Tron My /system/etc/permission/platform.xml seems to be ok in that section (it's exactly corresponding to the link you sent).

Comment: @bonnyz It remained a mystery until the end :)

Comment: @Antonio yet another Samsung tale!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to go under `Settings -> Apps -> NameOfApp -> Permissions` and activate the Storage permissions. I don't know why this comes deactivated by default if I have all the permissions on AndroidManifest.xml. I'm on a Moto G (3rd Gen) with Android Marshmallow 6.0.

Comment: I found out why it comes deactivated by default. Since `Marshmallow` you have to request permissions at runtime. See [this nice tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html)

Answer (score 3):

You first need to use `file.mkdirs()` instead of `folder.mkdir()`.

And if it also not worked then you need to check if you can access the sdcard or not.

For checking you can use below method.

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;

} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {

    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

} else {

    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

}
```

Read at official [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) .

Hope it will give some clue to you.

Comment: I already got [the same suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305100/cannot-create-directory-in-external-storage-although-permissions-are-apparently/33408627#comment54482064_33305100) from bonnyz, and [Madhukar Hebbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305100/cannot-create-directory-in-external-storage-although-permissions-are-apparently/33408627#comment54487944_33305100)...

Comment: one last suggestion to see that what's problem. Try hard coded path "**/mnt/sdcard**" instead of "**Environment.getExternalStorageState()**".

Comment: I am unable to create the directory also in "mnt/sdcard".

Comment: Have you read the last section of the question (Update) and the comments below the question? :) Yes, I did, and the code works for other devices.

Comment: I mean other device but  having same model and API **Samsung GT-I9506 with Android 4.3 (API18) ** .

Comment: No, I don't have another similar device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93667/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-antonio).

Comment: @Antonio : Thanks for bounty..:)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code. I have also emulated sd card on Lg g2 mini and I can only access external card in my package folder

```
for(File f : getExternalFilesDirs(null)){
    try {
        File f2 = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), "testFile");

        Log.d("test log", "file path " + f2.getAbsolutePath());
        f2.createNewFile();
        Log.d("test log", "file exist " + f2.exists());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("test log", "error");
    }
}
```

and output is:

```
D/test log? file path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.awesome.package/files/testFile
D/test log? file exist true
D/test log? file path /storage/external_SD/Android/data/my.awesome.package/files/testFile
D/test log? file exist true
```

Comment: Where do I find `getExternalFilesDirs`? I tried with `android.os.Environment.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` to no avail...

Comment: Sry it was called from activity, you can call it directly from context and it is from api 19. On older version this problem probably not exists so it is ok. (dis)advantage of this is when your app is uninstalled, all files that it creates are also removed.

Comment: I am afraid here we're dealing with api 18

Comment: You are lucky, it is from api 19 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html . You even dont need write permission from 19 api, if this article is right

Comment: In which way am I lucky? :)

Comment: you can make condition it api is 18 and less and access sd card old fashin way and if newer, you can use getExternalFilesDirs . I think it can work, with little praying

Comment: The point of this thread is that I have a very specific device with API 18 for which I cannot get a directory where my application can write.

Comment: I have same issue with my app, I will probably use internal memory for older devices with emulated sd cards and without permissions to write to external sd card or maybe someone will tell us how to solve it..

Comment: did you try to hardcode path, same as is in my log with yout package? It is not nice sollution, but it is interesting, if it is working. You can try to create file, and if it throw exception, then use internal memory

Comment: I cannot write on any memory, or any path

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     final File externalStoragePublicDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     File file = new File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, "test");
     file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: The outcome doesn't change.

Comment: Could you try this out in the Emulator or in any other device. I tried it in my Emulator and it works.

Comment: It's clear that the code is not the problem. The problem must be in some configuration of the device I am using. Thanks anyway for your help.