# What mistake am I doing in creating a directory and saving the image

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to click a image using camera of phone and trying to save the image in a separate directory in sdcard. I have tried many methods and I always get fileNotFoundException. I have both the following permissions defined in manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Below is the code which is giving me error:

```
 private void captureImage() {

 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}
```

My onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image

if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
if (data != null) {
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
postImage.setImageBitmap(photo); /* this is image view where you want to set image*/
Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
int count1 = count + 1;
createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo, "" + userId + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "mobileImageCapture" + count1);
}
}
}
```

Create directory and save file method:

```
 private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Toadways");
if (!direct.exists()) {
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Toadways/");
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/Toadways/"), fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
file.delete();
}
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

My Crash Log:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/DirName/56332edfad441746cbd15000_1451985027984mobile
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
W/System.err:     at toadways.ways.toad.toadways.ISayIPoll.createDirectoryAndSaveFile(ISayIPoll.java:1095
W/System.err:     at toadways.ways.toad.toadways.ISayIPoll.onActivityResult(ISayIPoll.java:779)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:   ... 15 more
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
......
</application>

</manifest>
```

My manifest file is too big, so I am posting part of it, which is needed.

Comment: Probably `DirName` doesn't exist and you didn't created it...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès If Dir doesnot exists I am creating a new using mkDirs, so it should not display that exception right?

Comment: No you created `/Toadways`...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: You edited the code since! Previously was `File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);` and that caused the problem, because `DirName` doesn't exist as the log message says...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes I changed that in my code. Still same error.

Comment: Then track where `DirName` appears in your code! Are your sure the log message is exactly the same? What is the code line that correspond to this error?

Comment: FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); this is the line

Comment: I have tried `createDirectoryAndSaveFile()` and it's working fine on my side. I can see that the folder **Toadways** has been created.

Comment: @FarazHussain Then why am I getting exception? any idea?

Comment: @FarazHussain Where can you see that folder?

Comment: Can you check whether the the folder is getting created or not? I have compiled your posted code, it's working good. Please post you manifest file too.

Comment: @FarazHussain Yes I am checking whether the folder is getting created or not. But I am not able to see it.

Comment: @FarazHussain I have posted it.

Comment: Which API level you are using?

Comment: @FarazHussain I have tested in both 22 and 23

Comment: In API 23, check **storage permission** in `App Info`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails) after checking for existing if it doesn't exists create it.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your_Path");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success
} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
}
```

Comment: you created another folder. the problem says that folder doesn't exists so your MkDir have some problems...

Comment: Another folder means? Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize the code.

Your code looks like this now:

```
    //If you are using Android Marshmallow, make sure storage permission is enabled.
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Toadways");
    if (!direct.exists())
    {
        direct.mkdir();
    }
    File file = new File(direct, fileName);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        file.delete();
    }
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also, you forgot to place the file extension:

```
createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo, "" + userId + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "mobileImageCapture" + count1 + ".png")
```