# Create folder in the ExternalStorage

Tags: java, android, file, io, directory

I am trying to write something to the `ExternalStorageDirectory` on my Android device. To test this, I tried to create a simple folder in this directory. As it has not been working I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853472/creating-a-directory-in-sdcard-fails) stackoverflow thread. When I use the most upvoted example code

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/map");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
success = folder.mkdir();
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success
} else {
    // Do something else on failure 
}
```

and set the givven `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, the creation of the folder is always failing - there is no exception, but after the execution `f.exists()` is still `false`.
I tested this on my `Nexus 5X` and the latest `Nexus 5X-Emulator`.

In the emulator `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns `not-mounted` although I mounted the `virtual SD-card` (this seems also strange to me). In my physical device it returns `mounted` - so I do not see any problem, why the code should not be working.

Any advices for the solution of the failure of the creation of the folder and/or the behaviour of the `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` are welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Thanks, this post solved it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this permission into manifiest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and create folder like this

```
String folder_main = "map";

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```