# How can I create a new directory on the SD card programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to create a new directory inside the SD card programmatically and I want to delete that directory also. How can I do this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To create a directory you can use the following code:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/your/directory");
try{
  if(dir.mkdir()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Directory is not created");
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To delete an empty directory, you can use this code:

```
boolean success = (new File("your/directory/name")).delete();
if (!success) {
   System.out.println("Deletion failed!");
}
```

To delete a non-empty directory, you can use this code:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

Maybe you also need this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This answer is also a good resource:

[How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: it didn't necessary to contain mkdir() method in try catch, because if folder exist, it's return false and didn't throw exception

Answer (score 24):

to create a directory, you could use

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dirName");

if(!myDirectory.exists()) {                                 
  myDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

to delete it,

```
 myDirectory.delete();
```

dont forget to add permission:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: No need to check for directory existence. `mkdirs()` will return true if the directory was created, false on failure or if the directory already existed.

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir() for

File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/abcabcabc"); 
directory.mkdir();


mkdirs() for
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Mani/abcxyz");
    directory.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DirName").mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create root directory and subfolder under it

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File myDir = new File(root + "/rootfoldername"+"/your sub folder name");

File dir=new File(root + "/rootfoldername"+"/your sub folder name");

myDir.mkdirs();

dir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have created directory and sub directory for my project like this..

```
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MP3 Music/"); //it is my root directory

        File favourite = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MP3 Music/" + "Favourites"); // it is my sub folder directory .. it can vary..

        try
        {
             if(dir.exists()==false) 
             {
                     dir.mkdirs();
             }
            /* else
             {
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Root Directory is already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }*/

             if(favourite.exists()==false) 
             {
                 favourite.mkdirs();
             }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();

        }
```