# File does not created in android?

Tags: android, file, permissions

When I was tried to create a New File, I got a error message.

Code:

```
try 
{
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + root.getAbsolutePath());
    File myFile = new File(root,"createNew.txt");
    myFile.createNewFile();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

`/mnt/sdcard` Permission as `d---------`

How do change Permission through programmatically?How do solve. Give me any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Note this point:

When I was used this code in command prompt, file is created successfully, In that code is:

```
`chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard`
```

Comment: Did you give `Write_External_storage` permission? Give this permission in your `Manifest.xml`

Comment: I already added this permission.

Comment: Are you trying this in your Device or Emulator?

Comment: Make sure. Both has the SdCard storage?

Comment: Yes. SDCard storage is available in `/mnt/sdcard`

Comment: [Just try this once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693077/940096)

Comment: I guess you are getting Root Permissions?? If I am correct then check is your testing device is rooted or not?? Emulators are not rooted. http://androidadvices.com/check-android-phone-rooted/ http://theunlockr.com/2012/06/20/how-to-check-whether-your-android-device-is-rooted-or-not/ http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html

Comment: Is it even possible to change the permissions on the SD card? I kind of doubt that...

Comment: whatever, never use hard-coded path to sdcard. Use Environment.getExteranlStorageDirectory() instead.

Comment: `File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());` i already try this one and now i am tried to access emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create the file:

```
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
//fos.write(...);
fos.close();
```

as the Java Doc says:

```
This method is not generally useful. For creating temporary files, use  
`createTempFile(String, String)` instead. For reading/writing files, use 
FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, or RandomAccessFile, all of which can create 
files.
```

Comment: I need to access only create a new file. Not write anything. Just only create a file. How?

Comment: try to create the output stream and close it without writing, and check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File) and http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

Answer (score 0):

1-Use this to get your sdk directory:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

2-Or may be your file path has some illegal characters(like blank space),in this case you need to replace them with legal equals characters.for example blank spaces with "\ ".you can see this pages:
[Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146727/runtime-getruntime-exec)
http://www.coderanch.com/t/498450/java/java/exec-command-not-able-deal
[Runtime.exec on argument containing multiple spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686592/runtime-exec-on-argument-containing-multiple-spaces)
[Combine paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/combine-paths-in-java)

Comment: see my question now. When i was tried to set permission as programmatically, at that time i can't create a new file. When i was tried to set permission through `command prompt` it's working.

Comment: I need to access only create a new file. Not write anything. Just only create a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                             "/yourfilename.txt");
    filename.createNewFile();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename2); 
    writer.write("Your content");
    writer.flush(); 
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't promote `e.printStackTrace()`. That's a bad habit. IDEs that put that by default truly hate you.