# Folder in sdcard0 invisible and unable to delete

Tags: android, storage, adb

I am using a Samsung NEXUS with Android 4.2.1. Today I deleted a folder that was created by an app that I developed. The app has been working fine until this for months. I manually deleted the folder (through ES3 file explorer app) for testing something. This did not give any error messages from Android and I thought it worked like any delete. However, I am not able to create THIS folder manually or through code anymore. Any other folder can be created and deleted either way.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");

System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

Both prints false.

Through the `adb shell` tried the following.

```
mkdir myfolder
mkdir failed for myfolder, File exists
```

However `ls` does not list `myfolder`

```
rmdir myfolder
rmdir failed for myfolder, No such file or directory
```

Any idea why this is happening or the way out would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got the right permissions in your manifest about accessing and writing on the SDCARD

Comment: @RvdK Thanks for the response. Yes the app has got all the required permissions. Infact the problem here is not the app. I can get the app running by using a different name for the folder and it works just fine. The issue here is with the already created folder `myfolder` which I deleted and is now not visible anywhere in the sdcard (internal storage). However neither adb nor the file explorer allows a folder to be created with that name. I need to create the same folder in my tablet and avoid any changes in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the tablet and the issue disappeared. Must have been a platform issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
To create a directory you can use the following code:

File dir = new File("path/to/your/directory");
try{
  if(dir.mkdir()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Directory is not created");
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

To delete an empty directory, you can use this code:
boolean success = (new File("your/directory/name")).delete();
if (!success) {
   System.out.println("Deletion failed!");
}

To delete a non-empty directory, you can use this code:

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Original Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693077/2931489

Try this answer

if (!sdcarddir.exists())
   sdcarddir.mkdir();

Check in all folders by doing this...

String[] myDirectories = {"","",""......}; // your list of directories

for (String directory : myDirectories ) {
  File file = new File(directory);
   if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
      // Do something you have found your directory

}

Or try this..

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/somedir");
if(f.isDirectory()) {
   ....
}

else .... Make directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code. This is already working fine in my app. Please see my response to the comment above

Comment: have u tested on other device ?

Comment: Please next time you copy someone elses answer, also provide a link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693077/47351

Comment: @BabulPatel yes, it runs fine on any other device. All I need is the folder created with the same name as before. This is not happening either manually or through the app.

Comment: What error occur if you create folder manually.

Check for that is your folder hidden or something ?

Before any folder if you insert .(DOT) then android consider it as hidden folder... so check that

Comment: The output when manually creating (as included in the question) is that it says "File exists". In `adb shell`, `ls -la` does list the hidden folders but `myfolder` is not listed. So I understand it is not hidden.