# can't create folder programmatically on external storage - Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-file

This is my code:

```
boolean success = false;
Log.d(TAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/myFolder" );
myFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/myFolder" );

if( myFolder.exists() ){
    Log.d(TAG, "FOLDER EXISTS");
}else{

    success = myFolder.mkdir();

    if( success ){
        // Do something on success

    } else {
        // Do something else on failure 
        throw new RuntimeException("File Error in writing new folder");
}
```

What is wrong?

Running it on `HTC Desire HD - android 2.3.5` will cause this output:

```
D/DVA_HLUI Application(25723): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/myFolder
E/AndroidRuntime(25723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.DVA_HLUI.DVAHLUI_App: java.lang.RuntimeException: File Error in writing new folder
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3920)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1098)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: File Error in writing new folder
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at com.DVA_HLUI.DVAHLUI_App.onCreate(DVAHLUI_App.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:984)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3917)
E/AndroidRuntime(25723):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2131051/940096)

Comment: Do you have the `android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`permission set in your manifest? Asking because there is no mention in the OP.

Comment: is the error generated from above code only or when you do something after the folder is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure just try to create folder like below -

```
success = myFolder.mkdirs();
```

instead of

```
success = myFolder.mkdir();
```

as per [mkdirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) And, don't forget to add the below permisstion into your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also have a look at this answer - [How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130932/940096)

Comment: Hey, thks for answering, and sorry for delay in response. `mkdirs()` was the correct indication! turns out that `mkdirs()` creates all directories in the path while `mkdir()` won't!

Answer (score 0):

You should Use This Permission in your mainfest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```