# Create empty file with android init script

Tags: android, android-source, init

Is it possible to create empty file in android source code with init rc script like we create folder.
mkdir /tmp creates folder but
touch /tmp/test doesn't do anything.

pls help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create directory automatically on SD card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: I am asking how to create file with init.rc script in android source code not via androd app.

Answer (score 5):

the 'write' or 'copy' command works.

but please make ensure the commands are added after the filesystems are mounted, for example, at the end of "on post-fs-data"

```
    on post-fs-data
        ...
        write /data/non-empty-file 0
        ...
        copy /dev/null /data/empty-file
```