# mkdirs aways return false in Android 5.1

Tags: android, exception

I searched these issues, but couldn't resolve it.Please help me in solving this problem

That is my mkdir code:

```
File _sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // sdcard path is /storage/emulate/0
File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath, "CreateFolder");
boolean _isCreate = _dirPath.mkdir();
if (_isCreate) {
   tvResult.append(_dirPath + " mkdir success");
} else {
   tvResult.append(_dirPath + " mkdir fail");
}
```

my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.createfolder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My device android version is: 5.1.1, 12GB free space, and the code run regular under 5.0

While running the app I encountered this Exception :

```
android.system.ErrnoException: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied) when I debug step into File.mkdirs
```

Comment: what is the new folder that you want to create? as it is, there is nothing to create so it returns false.

Comment: @muratgu No, "CreateFolder" not a dir or file in storage, I make sure via adb shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [DocumentFile](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) for accessing SDcard from android 4.4 and above. More detail in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)

Comment: I'm fail to create create directory via run this statement : DocumentFile.fromFile(_sdcardPath).createDirectory("CreateFolder");

Comment: DocumentFile.fromFile(_sdcardPath).canWrite() return true

Comment: Take time to read the document links and find the examples code for it. There are some APIs to take the access sdcard permission. I don't have experiences on it, but I am sure that is solution you need.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I try like https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#create, but the devices only start explorer, so I couldn't create a directory or file.

Comment: Yeah, that you go through half of road. When it starts the explorer, user will grant your app the access storage (sd) permission. Then on activityForResult do with the result code [like this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#results).

Comment: But I want to save a bitmap on my app, can I do it on background?

Comment: I am afraid that you can not do it without getting permission from user. So, I think you need take permission in the first time run app, if user granted it, continue your app, otherwise finish your app and show it in the next time.

Comment: You should read my answer related links. The reading, writing SD files process was changed and You know that is a security feature on new Android versions. I think you can not find any other solutions without taking permission from user. I suggest you 2 options:1:Write on internal storage, 2:Take permission at first time lauch app.

Comment: I write cache on Context.getCacheDir, and set MemoryPersistence to MQTTAndroidClient. And I read these links, good data, thank you.

Comment: There are some risks on this folder as its docs. Be careful. Anyway, do what you want that make it works.

Answer (score 3):

**OP remembered to add the exception to his/her question. This answer is not relevant anymore.**

--

You are not giving it a new folder to create. Try this instead:

```
...
File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath + "/CreateFolder");
...
```

Comment: I try it, but I fail.

Comment: try mkdirs() instead

Answer (score 2):

I found nothing is wrong with your code. Based on [mkdir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) and [this file doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), I think the folder existed.

> *false* on failure or if the directory already existed.

It means the following code:

```
File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath, "CreateFolder");
boolean _isCreate = _dirPath.mkdir();
```

only attempt to (re)create the existing folder `/storage/emulate/0`, thus, returned `false`.

To create new folder, try this:

```
File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath + "/CreateFolder");
boolean _isCreate = _dirPath.mkdir();// this will create folder CreateFolder
```

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: The folder not existed, I can't found it on adb shell

Comment: I try the code :File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath + "/CreateFolder"); and fail to create too.

Answer (score 1):

check if `/storage/emulate/0/CreateFolder` exists before `mkdir` like this:

```
File _sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File _dirPath = new File(_sdcardPath, "CreateFolder");
final boolean dirExisted = _dirPath.exists();
if (dirExisted && _dirPath.isFile()) {
    _dirPath.delete();
}
if (dirExisted) {
    tvResult.append(_dirPath + " dir existed");
    return;
}
boolean _isCreate = _dirPath.mkdir();
if (_isCreate) {
    tvResult.append(_dirPath + " mkdir success");
} else {
    tvResult.append(_dirPath + " mkdir fail");
}
```

If the path exists a `file`, try to `delete` it.If is a `dir`, no need to create it anymore.

Comment: "CreateFolder" is a new name of my storage, my storage not have any file or dir name "createFolder"