# Android app: How do I create a directory in the internal storage

Tags: java, android, file, io, directory

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to create a directory/file through an android app to the internal storage. I have the following code:

```
public class Environment extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public static String FILE_PATH;
    //other unimportant variables

    public Environment(Conext context) {
        super(context);
        FILE_PATH = context.getFilesDir() + "/My Dir/";
        File customDir = new File(FILE_PATH);
        if(!customDir.exists())
            System.out.println("created my dir: " + customDir.mkdir());

        File test = new File(FILE_PATH + "testFile.txt");
        try {
            if(!test.exists())
                System.out.println("created test: " + test.createNewFile());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //other unimportant stuff
    }
}
```

I then use ES File Explorer to see if it created the file and I don't see the directory/file anywhere despite it printing out "true" for the System.out.println() calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925801/6021469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path where you are creating file is in apps private location. Generally you can't access it from outside. It's actually created in apps data folder. However it seems you want to write in external folder.
To write in the external storage, you must request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

code:

```
    String folder_main = "My Dir";

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
    File test = new File(f , "testFile.txt");
```

Here you will find how to you will create folder/file in external storage.

[Save a File on External Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage)

Comment: Still can't find the the directory, and now it says that it couldn't create the directory: "create my dir: false".  Also get a "java.io.IOException: Permission Denied" when trying to create the test file

Comment: Notice the upper portion code of this answer where permission is being given to your app.

Comment: @ashubuntu Yea I added that to the manifest, still isn't working

Comment: >  "create my dir: false". Also get a "java.io.IOException: Permission Denied". So obviously problem is related to permission. Do you grant permission explicitly? If not allow it from `settings>app>yourapp>permission`. @Ryan

Comment: I explicitly grant permissions in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and I also went to the settings and gave storage permissions in there and it still can't create the directory. I also tried changing the directory to: `File customDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Dir");` which also didn't work

Comment: Ok, I don't know what I did differently, but while hopelessly retrying the same things over and over again, something clicked and it's now working. Thanks for all of the help

Comment: Actually it turns out manually going into the settings and giving the app storage permissions fixed my problem. Is there anyway I can do this automatically though?

Comment: would you please try solution I provided above.

Comment: So my solution works? As far privacy policy, android gives those authority to the users. You can search "how to seek permission on android" and will find  a lot of resources. @Ryan

Comment: Yea I had to look into requesting permission for read and writing to storage and everything is working fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below:

```
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file =  new File(directory,”fileName”);
String data = “TEST DATA”;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(“fileName”, true); // save
fos.write(data.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This will write file in Device's internal storage (/data/user/0/com.yourapp/)

Hope this helps!