# How to create directory programatically in your app project?

Tags: android, android-file

I want to create  directory in my android project. I have tried below code I could not find any directory in my project.

```
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "files");
myDir.mkdir();
if(!myDir.exists())
myDir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: make sure you given permission in your manifest.

Comment: given permission

Comment: Do you want to create dir in internal storage or external?

Comment: you want to create directory in project file structure or mobile memory ??

Comment: i want to create in my project file structure

Comment: which version of device you are using for testing? from 6.0 you have to get dynamic permission

Comment: I  want to create directory in my project folder and I want to create file in  created directory.

Comment: Why you want to create directory in Android Project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Comment: after made an API call i am having google font URL it might be anything whenever I made an API call like one time it will come Roboto.tff next time anything. i want to do make directory inside the project.save the ttf into the directory.

Comment: @sowmya You want to create it at runtime right? Using code and not when you are writing code ? Check my answer below

Comment: if i get robotto first time make a directory and save the file in robotto.Next time if i get another one have to check if is exists else create a new directory for another ttf

Comment: You so you can create as shown in my code below and inside that you can check if you have the same or another and save accordingly. I think it will answer your question

Comment: you can't create a directory in your PC with code that is running on your Android device.

Comment: its confusing how to create a directory in my  android project structure

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a Dir in your internal storage you can do it in the below method

```
File mydir = context.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
if (!mydir.exists())
{
     mydir.mkdirs();
}
```

`getFilesDir()` returns a File object to a directory that is private to your application only.

`getDir()` enables you to create any file or directory in the internal memory, which is also accessible by other applications depending on the mode you create it.

`getCacheDir()` returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem but doesn't enable you to create Dir there. You can create a file though.

Please note that this file will be stored in internal memory and can be cleared by system as well as user manually on clearing cache.